# When does "The Mandalorian" take place?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In the first episode of the new *The Mandalorian* TV show, it is mentioned that the Empire is gone. We can then infer that this show is set after *Return of the Jedi*.

Do we know exactly when the show takes place, in-universe?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

About five years after *Return of the Jedi* according to Jon Favreau, the producer, who mentions as such in a behind the scenes clip at the Star Wars Celebration event in Chicago as reported by /Film.

> “This series takes place about five years after *Return of the Jedi*,” executive producer and showrunner **Jon Favreau** says in the clip. “This is a character you’ve never met before in a period of time that you’ve never seen.”
>
> <sub>[/Film, ‘The Mandalorian’ Footage Description: Sorry, Boba Fett, There’s a New Bounty Hunter in Town](https://www.slashfilm.com/the-mandalorian-footage-description/)</sub>

Comment: "a period of time that you’ve never seen" Only in the sense that no shows/movies have covered it. #LegendsIsTheTrueCanon

Comment: @Harabeck didn't "caravan of courage" take place around this time, so we did see it in movies?

Comment: @CBredlow I only vaguely remember that movie, but wikipedia says that it took place between ESB and RotJ. Its sequel, Ewoks: The Battle for Endor, also apparently took place before Return of the Jedi.

Answer (score 2):

The Mandalorian takes place in 9 ABY (After the Battle of Yavin), or 5 years after Return of the Jedi.

Comment: This would be improved with sources