# Were Anakin and “The Asset” in the Mandalorian born in the same year?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

As has been [established](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222986/when-does-the-mandalorian-take-place) *The Mandalorian* takes place five years after the events of *Return of the Jedi*. If my maths are correct this would put the show happening in 9 ABY.

In the show we are introduced to a character being referred to as “The Asset” in S01E01. This character is the target of a bounty and the only identifying information is that they are 50 years old. This would make “The Asset” being born in the year 41 BBY…

Well, guess who was also born in 41 BBY, none other than [Anakin Skywalker](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker)! It has also been <s>[confirmed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/143618/57310)</s> [not actually confirmed](https://comicbook.com/starwars/2019/12/24/star-wars-darth-vader-emperor-palpatine-father-darth-plagueis/) that Darth Sidious used the force to manipulate the midi-chlorians to create Anakin.

So here is where we get to my theory…

In S01E02 we find out “The Asset” is actually a child of the same species as Yoda. In *The Last Jedi*, Snoke talks about “Darkness rises and the light to meet it.” If we consider Sidious creating Anakin as an act of darkness, could and would there have been a light side counter to balance this… Could “The Child” have been created by the Force as well?

Now, my theory does hinge on the title question as I need to confirm that Anakin and the child were born in the same year.

### Is there any confirmation “The Asset” (aka: “The Child”) was born in *precisely* 41 BBY?

Comment: I'm guessing you're going to need to wait for at least the end of the first season to find out.

Comment: "50 years old" can be an approximation (like "it's on a his fifties"), to indicate the age of the creature. It doesn't implies that the creature is effectively and actually "50 years old"

Comment: ignores all the clues related to cloning

Comment: @NKCampbell Pershing is trying to _create_ a clone of the asset.

Comment: @iammg I didn't get the impression the beacon worked that way. Apparently they have a number/code that relates to attributes, but they only had the last four(?) of the asset's which was age.

Comment: @Skooba I believe it was birth year

Comment: In fact we do know that they wanted to child to extract something from it - car of Episode 3. We do not yet know the origin of the child one way or the other, nor their further intentions with it.

Comment: @Edlothiad, yep, it would be easier to store birth year(which won't ever change) than the age(that naturally changes all the time) in the id

Comment: `In S01E02 we find out “The Asset” is actually a child of the same species as Yoda.` ~> What special details did you get in the second episode about his species? The visual cue was already there in the first episode.

Comment: "Well, guess who was also born in 41 BBY, none other than Anakin Skywalker! It has also been confirmed that Darth Sidious used the force to manipulate the midi-chlorians to create Anakin." Actually, Lucasfilm has denied that Palpatine had used the Force to create Anakin.

Comment: The dang 50 years messes up my entire pet theory which is that Yoda's species procreates by reincarnation when one dies via ghost midi-chlorians. Maybe there may even only be one at a time, So Baby Yoda *is* indeed baby Yoda Reborn. Oh well, back to the drawing board....

Comment: @Marakai Yaddle in the prequel series also messed up that theory.

Comment: @Marakai `Baby Yoda is indeed baby Yoda Reborn` ~> Actually, Baby Yoda is original Yoda (not reborn or anything). Season 2 will show time travel. Officially confirmed!

Comment: @BabyYoda Isn't time travel more Star Trek than Star Wars? :P

Answer (score 2):

## Most likely.

The Clone Wars broke out in 22 BBY, and the events of *The Phantom Menace* took place ten years before that, according to dialogue in *Attack of the Clones*. Anakin was nine years old during the events of *The Phantom Menace*, making the year of his birth 41 BBY.

According to the Client in *The Mandalorian*: Chapter One, the Child is fifty years old, which is likely the truth. This is in the year 9 ABY, which we know is the year due to comments made by Jon Favreau at *Star Wars* Celebration 2019, where he said that the series takes place about five years after *Return of the Jedi*. Therefore, the Child was born in the year 41 BBY, the same as Anakin Skywalker.

Comment: Yes, but what confirmation do we have that the client is telling the truth about the age, or that the age is _precise_?  That is what I am looking for,